# How to pass Dictionary to web service in android using restclient?

Tags: java, android, wcf, hashmap

I have done calling wcf service in web application by passing Collection of dictionaries to a method. I want to achieve the same thing in android using ksoap2.

Here is the way i pass it,

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpclient.getParams(), 30000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpclient.getParams(), 50000);
    JSONObject InputDic = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject ProfileDictionary = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray InputDicArray = new JSONArray(); 
    JSONArray ProfileDicArray = new JSONArray(); 
    //Input Dictionary to the Common Service
    try{
    InputDic.put("GURefID", 0);
    InputDic.put("ProfileType","Customer");
    InputDic.put("SecurityToken","");
    InputDic.put("SkillID", 1);
    InputDic.put("WorkflowServerID", 1);
    InputDic.put("XMPPUserName", "testuser");    
    InputDic.put("XMPPPassword", "testuser");
    InputDic.put("XMPPServerName", "test");      
    InputDic.put("GUTranID", 12130);
    //Input Profile Dictionary
    EditText txtProfileCode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittextprofilecode);
    ProfileDictionary.put("ProfileCode", txtProfileCode.getText().toString().trim());
    EditText guAddressID = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittextcustcode);            
    ProfileDictionary.put("guAddressID", txtProfileCode.getText().toString().trim());
    String ProfileTitle =   title.getItemAtPosition(title.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
    ProfileDictionary.put("Title", ProfileTitle.toString().trim());
    ProfileDictionary.put("Gender", "Male");
    EditText txtCustName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittextCustname);           
    ProfileDictionary.put("FirstName",txtCustName.getText().toString().trim()  );
    EditText txtPhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittextPhoneNo);       
    ProfileDictionary.put("Phonenumber", txtPhone.getText().toString().trim());
    EditText txtMobile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittextMobileno);    
     ProfileDictionary.put("Mobilenumber",  txtMobile.getText().toString().trim());
     EditText txtfax = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittextfax);    
     ProfileDictionary.put("Faxnumber",  txtfax.getText().toString().trim());
     EditText txtemail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittextemail);    
     ProfileDictionary.put("E-mail",  txtemail.getText().toString().trim());
     EditText txtskype = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittextskype);    
     ProfileDictionary.put("Skypeid",  txtskype.getText().toString().trim());
     EditText txtgtalk = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittextgtalk);    
     ProfileDictionary.put("Googletalkid",  txtgtalk.getText().toString().trim());
     EditText txtTwitterid = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittexttwitter);    
     ProfileDictionary.put("Twitterid",  txtTwitterid.getText().toString().trim());
     EditText txtfacebook = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittextfacebook);    
     ProfileDictionary.put("Facebookid",  txtfacebook.getText().toString().trim());
     InputDicArray.put(InputDic);
     ProfileDicArray.put(ProfileDictionary);
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    }



    try {
       JSONObject InputMessage = new JSONObject();

        JSONObject mParams = new JSONObject();
        mParams.put("InputDictionary", InputDicArray);
        mParams.put("AdditionalDictionary1", ProfileDicArray);
        mParams.put("UseAdditionalDictionary", true);
        mParams.put("AdditionalDictionaryName1","ProfileDictionary");
        mParams.put("SecurityToken", 323);
        mParams.put("SessionID", 2423);
        mParams.put("UseWorkflowID",true); 
        mParams.put("UseGUSessionID",true);
        mParams.put("WorkflowID",0);
        mParams.put("WorkflowType", "");
        mParams.put("WorkflowName", "Profile");
        InputMessage.put("DuoWorkflowInvokeProxy",mParams);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(InputMessage.toString(), "UTF-8");

        se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_LEN, String.valueOf(InputMessage.toString().length())));
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "text/xml"); 
        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "text/xml"); 
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
             response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                        String sResponse;
                        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

                        while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            s = s.append(sResponse);
                        }
                    System.out.println("Response: ");
                    Log.v("hari", "Response : ");
        }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

            e.printStackTrace(); 

    }
```

am getting an error like below

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: Edited the answer.. check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose"); 

httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json;odata=verbose");
```

instead

```
httpost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 

httpost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

as V3 payloads currently don't support application/json

Comment: This also does not work bro , i think the problem is with the way i send the request